# Dynamic TF Publishing Discrepancy Between Foxy and Humble

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have posted an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/issues/2161); however, no one responds to it. So I start to wonder if it is my own mistake.
It begins from one day when I transform a piece of ROS foxy code into the Humble environment.

> rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeTopicsInterface::SharedPtr node_topics_handle = this->get_node_topics_interface();

> std::unique_ptr*<*tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster*>* tf_broadcaster_ = nullptr;

> tf_broadcaster_ = std::make_unique*<*tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster*>*(node_topics_handle);

It will give you an error.
"***passed non-default qos overriding options without providing a parameters interface**.*"

[image: image description]

You may wonder why you want to write it like this.
Why not use 'this' directly. It is because by using ***node_topics_handle***, I can isolate different functions in different classes without passing the shared printer node everywhere.

Please, tell me how to publish dynamic TF with ***node_topics_handle***.

Thanks.

Operating System:
Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Installation type:
binaries
Version or commit hash:
ROS humble
DDS implementation:
Fast-RTPS
Client library (if applicable):
rclcpp

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/414157/publish-dynamic-tf-with-this-%3Eget_node_topics_interface()-works-in-foxy-but-not-in-humble.-(passed-non-default-qos-overriding-options-without-providing-a-parameters-interface)/) by [BlueBird](https://answers.ros.org/users/98868/bluebird/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2023-04-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got an answer from the [Url](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/1407).
It should be written as

> tf_broadcaster_ = std::make_unique<tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster>(node_topics_handle, tf2_ros::DynamicBroadcasterQoS(), rclcpp::PublisherOptions());

Any additions or suggestions are very welcome.
Thanks, anyway.

---

Originally posted by [BlueBird](https://answers.ros.org/users/98868/bluebird/) with karma: 20 on 2023-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0